# C++ iterator to last element of a set

Tags: c++, iterator, set

I have the following code in C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    set<int> a;
    int n;

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
      cin>>n;
      a.insert(n);
    }

    cout << *a.end();
    return 0;
}
```

Why is it always printing "3" instead of the greatest element in the set? Replacing `cout << *a.end();` with `cout << *--a.end();` works fine.

Comment: `end()` is **not** pointing to the last element, it is pointing **one past** it. C++ ranges are closed at the front, open at the back: `[begin, end)`.

Comment: [This `std::set::end` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/end) have a nice figure illustrating it.

Comment: I thought it was closed at the back too. Thanks!

Answer (score 59):

Just use `*a.rbegin()` which points to the last element in the set

Answer (score 17):

> ```
> *a.end()
> ```

Undefined behaviour. In C++ iterator terminology, "end" does not mean the same thing as "last element".

> Replacing `cout << *a.end();` with `cout << *--a.end();` works fine.

Consider a reverse iterator: `*a.rbegin()`.

Keep in mind that both `begin()` and `rbegin()` only return dereferencable iterators if the container is not empty. For empty containers, `begin() == end()` and `rbegin() == rend()`.

Comment: OMG! I always used (--a.end()), but now i know the best option ;)

Answer (score 9):

> Why is it always printing "3" instead of the greatest element in the
>   set?

Because `a.end()` is *one past* the end of your vector.  It doesn't hold any valid data, it's a marker for the end of your vector. As in:

```
for(auto i = a.begin(); i != a.end(); ++i) 
    // do stuff with i
```

EDIT: (thanks to Nathan) dereferencing `a.end()` yields the dreaded undefined behaviour.  Anything could have happened: get a `3`, get the last element in the set, could even have canceled X-mas!!!

Comment: May also want to say that it is UB

Answer (score 6):

To find the last element of a set what we can do is use an iterator that points to last of the of the set and then decrement the iterator to reach the last element as set.end() represent the iterator that points just outside the end of set.

```
auto it = s.end();
it--;
cout<<(*it)<<endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

For `set<int>s`

You can also use `*prev(s.end())`