# How to output the last element of a set in C++?

Tags: c++

When I insert 3 elements into a set and then call `*s.end()`, I get the correct output of 3, as follows:

```
set<int> s; 

s.insert(1);
s.insert(2);
s.insert(3);
cout << *s.end();
```

I then erase 2 values and insert 11, as follows:

```
s.erase(3);
s.erase(2);

s.insert(11);

cout << *s.end();
```

The new expected output of `*s.end()` should be 11. But the output is showing 2. No clue from where this 2 is coming. Any ideas?

Expected Output: 3 11
Actual Output: 3 2

It's not clear where 2 is coming from.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ iterator to last element of a set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41302441/c-iterator-to-last-element-of-a-set)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `end/cend/rend/crend` member functions of any standard container do *not* return an iterator to the last element of the sequence. They return a sentinal value, semantically equivalent to one-past-the-end. Dereferencing them is undefined behavior, so you can't rely on any results printed out in this example.

You can fix this by

```
cout << *std::prev(s.end());
```

Comment: or `s.rbegin()`

Comment: @MikeVine Good point, this is preferrable I guess.